# how can i change the owner of the ecr20 token aka msg.sender to a new owner if anything happened to the owner(inactivity for a period of time)

Tags: solidity

I want to make a function that changes the ownership of the ecr20 token incase the true owner is killed or anything related. how can we test his inactivity to check if we should transfer ownership? and is it possible to split the ownership in equity between like 10 people

Comment: There is an ambiguity in `owner of the erc20 token` it could either mean the owner of the erc20 token contract or holder/owner of the token itself. Which one did you mean? I assumed the latter one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One small thing to point out is `msg.sender` does not necessarily refer to the owner of the erc20 token, but it refers to the address that calls the smart contract function. So the functionality you are looking for you need to override the erc20 token contract. One thing you can do is maintain a mapping to track when the last time an owner did something the erc20 token:

```
mapping (address=>uint256) lastUpdated;
```

With every function call, you can update the `lastUpdated` variable.

```
lastUpdated = block.timestamp;
```

Whether or not you want to update it for view functions is up to you. Now you can create an extra function on the ERC20 token that enables anyone to transfer the token to a new owner if there is a certain period of inactivity.

```
function removeTokenFromInactiveAccount(address inactiveUser, address transferTo) public {
  require(block.timestamp > lastUpdated[inactiveUser]+inactivePeriod, "Inactive period threshold not reached");
  transferFrom(inactiveUser, transferTo, balanceOf(inactiveUser));
}
```

But there is a problem here, the contract has to send the token on behalf of the inactive user. This is not possible if the inactive user does not increase the `allowance` for the contract. So a workaround would be to for every erc20 owner the allowance for the contract address could be set to a large number or update the allowance every time the balance increases. Here is a sample of the first approach:

```
_allowed[owner][this(address)] = // <large number>
```

The above example assumes [Openzepplin ERC20 implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> *how can we test his inactivity to check if we should transfer ownership*

In a Solidity contract, you can only check activity directly related to this contract. Your code does not have access to read other transactions of the `owner` or any other user to check whether they are active elsewhere. In the example below, the owner needs to invoke the `ping()` function at least once a year - otherwise the `claimOwnership()` unlocks for anyone else to claim the ownership.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyContract is Ownable {
    uint256 lastPingTimestamp;

    // can be executed only by the owner
    function ping() public onlyOwner {
        lastPingTimestamp = block.timestamp;
    }

    // can be executed by anyone
    function claimOwnership() public {
        // reverts if at least a year hasn't passed since the last owner ping
        require(lastPingTimestamp < block.timestamp - 356 days);

        // make the user invoking this function the new owner
        _transferOwnership(msg.sender);
        lastPingTimestamp = block.timestamp;
    }
}
```

Note that `claimOwnership()` in this example is simplified and not resistant against frontrunning. In real-life scenarion, you might want to add some commit logic or a list of preauthorized addresses that are able to claim ownership.

---

> *is it possible to split the ownership in equity between like 10 people*

OpenZeppelin published the [AccessControl](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control) library that allows you to give authorized persmissions to several addresses. Here's an example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";

contract MyContract is AccessControl {
    constructor(address[] memory admins) {
        for (uint i; i < admins.length; i++) {
            _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, admins[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is that like a multisignature smart contract

Comment: @AdrianAchour Not really. In the second example, all users with `DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE` have the same privileges and can act individually. If you need a multisig, you'll need to implement an array of users already that already confirmed the action, and allow performing the action only if the length of the array equals the predefined amount of confirmations.

Comment: does the balance of the inactive owner also get transfered when you transfer ownership

Comment: @AdrianAchour Not in this example, however it is technically possible to implement the owner balance transfer as well.

Comment: is the _transferownership function in the standard ECR20 functions

Comment: @AdrianAchour There's nothing related to contract administrative roles in the ERC20 standard.